# How to access Laravel storage through URL?

Tags: laravel

I put I file in the Laravel storage, that is linked to public. How can I access this file through the URL? I get 404 back.

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('foo/bar.pdf, $pdfview);
```

Links I tried, that are not working:

- http://localhost/public/storage/foo/bar.pdf
- http://localhost/storage/foo/bar.pdf
- http://localhost/foo/bar.pdf
- http://localhost/bar.pdf

Comment: How's your `filesystem.php` set up? In there you should have defined a `'url'`.

Comment: assuming you are using local storage. have you created symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`? check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-urls).

Comment: my filesystem.php is untouched (Laravel 9). For the public disk I have `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',` and APP_URL is `http://localhost` The symlink is created as I wrote. And http://localhost/storage/foo/bar.php is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{asset('storage/foo/bar.pdf')}}
```

This should be one the correct way to get the url of the file. Before running this, make sure, you have run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and a shortcut link named `storage` has been created inside your public folder.

Also, make sure that there is a file in:

```
storage/app/public/foo/bar.pdf
```

because this is the place where laravel tries to find the file.

It could be by permission as well. Try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: I want to access it from the URL in the browser

Comment: you mean on the blade file, or by hitting directly on the browser? have you run `php artisan storage:link` on project root folder? And is there `storage` shortcut` inside public folder? If yes, you can access it as `http://localhost/storage/foo/bar.pdf` Let me know once you try methods, I mentioned here.

Comment: Yes, as written the storage is linked to public. The files from `storage/app/public` are available as a symlink in `public/storage`. All URL links in my questions are not working, including the one you provided. If this helps: I am using nginx with a server block that has my public folder as the root folder

Comment: @PeterPan if this is ngnix, its probably permission issue. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it. `GET /storage/foo/bar.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 6626 "http://localhost:3000/"`

Comment: @PeterPan another thing is that, where is your file located? You have not mentioned that one yet... and are you accessing your projcet via  just `http://localhost` or there is some virtualhost like `http://laravel.test`??

Comment: My server block has the server_name app.local wich I added to my hosts file. I can access the `public/index.php` either through `http://app.local` or `http://localhost/app/public`. But the storage access does not work neither for the one nor the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244608/discussion-between-saroj-shrestha-and-peterpan).